# Can't run my code on Eclipse IDE for Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I've just installed  Eclipse for Java but when I run my code it gives an error saying 'Module myproject not found' Can someone give a hand pls????
Exact error code:
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module myproject not found

Comment: Does your integration support launching module applications?

Comment: How can I check whether it does or not? I'm quite a code newbie :)

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50334794/java-10-eclipse-maven-java-lang-module-findexception-module-myproject-not-fo) help?

Comment: Soo I need to download Eclipse Photon? Did I get it right?

Comment: Try this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49520858/error-occurred-during-initialization-of-boot-layer-findexception-module-not-fou

Comment: Perhaps it would be better if we discussed this in chat.