# I just installed eclipse, why won't eclipse run any of my code?

Tags: java, eclipse

I cannot get eclipse to run any code whatsoever. I have just begun using eclipse and think I may not have installed the jre/jdk properly because I have tried running different code and always get the same error. This is the error message I got as soon as I opened the workbench and tried to run something the first time:

Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module tutorial1 not found

Everything appears to be there in my file system, but then again I have never done a successful build so I'm not entirely sure how it should look. I'm just getting started learning java development and this is rather discouraging. Why won't eclipse run any code? Are there other steps I should have taken before installing eclipse?

I have tried running different code and always get the same boot layer message. I have also tried installing multiple versions of the jre, jdk, and eclipse and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse - module not found when adding module-info.java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47511379/eclipse-module-not-found-when-adding-module-info-java)

Comment: Someone has already answered this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47511379/eclipse-module-not-found-when-adding-module-info-java)