# Module not found even though its there

Tags: java, java-module, module-info

I've got a slight issue running my Java Application (it works fine when I run it through Maven). I get the error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module moduleName not found
```

The module is there within my `src` folder, and my folder structure is as follows:

for the `module-info.java` -> `src/module-info.java`

for my class `src/main/java/frogger/game/MainMenu.java`

Weirdly enough, when I write out the name of the module in my `module-info.java` file it starts working again, but breaks after a few runs.

EDIT:

Changing the `module-info` location to `src/main/java` fixed the issue, however, it breaks my Maven install command and throws the following error:

```
Execution default-compile of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile failed.: IllegalArgumentException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project projectName: Execution default-compile of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile failed.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-compile of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile failed.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init> (Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init> (Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init> (Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.languages.java.jpms.AsmModuleInfoParser.parse (AsmModuleInfoParser.java:80)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.languages.java.jpms.AsmModuleInfoParser.getModuleDescriptor (AsmModuleInfoParser.java:65)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.languages.java.jpms.LocationManager.resolvePaths (LocationManager.java:113)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.preparePaths (CompilerMojo.java:219)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCompilerMojo.java:762)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute (CompilerMojo.java:168)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

Comment: If your source root is `src/main/java/`, then module-info must be at `src/main/java/module-info.java`

Comment: Are you using eclipse or netbeans

Comment: I'm using Eclipse

Comment: @ernest_k It works when I do that, but then my Maven breaks ...

Comment: @mievvin and what does "break" mean then(for Maven)?

Comment: @Naman it says ``Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile`` . I'll paste the longer message in the main post

Comment: @mievvin Do take a look at [upgrading the `maven-compiler-plugin`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51586202/1746118) as well. Might just help(without looking at the complete logs.) ... Indeed that should solve the issue, given the stack trace in the updated question. Do confirm to close this as a duplicate.

Comment: @Naman ok i've upgraded it, it went through it seems but now my tests are all giving errors, gives me this for them all ``java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make testing.BuilderTests() accessible: module moduleNAme does not "opens testing" to unnamed module @68267da0`` . I've added ``opens testing;`` to the module-info but it says that ``testing`` is an unrecognized package

Comment: Edit - Managed to fix this new error by making all my test cases public and the classes too

Comment: @mievvin sure marking this as a duplicate for now, if you see any other value add do create a Q&A specifically around that.

Answer (score 1):

1. One way is create new project and then you were asked to write name of your project. After that you were asked `Create module-info.java`. You have to select **Don't create** option. After that create your project same as original project.
2. Other way is go to your run configuration and add your classes locations to the vm argument and also module name/path to main. [Further explain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47512521/11383441)

Comment: Wouldn't the second option make it not be able to work on other computers though, since it'd have a hardcoded path from my PC specifically?

Comment: No, That argument setting only applied for current project. I like to heavily suggest you to follow the first option. It is worked for me.

Comment: Honestly I would, but the amount of time I've spent making this one work with Maven makes me not want to do it as it will most likely break the Maven again, it's also all committed into GitHub from the start of the project so just making a new one isn't really ideal. I managed to get it working with the suggestion from @ernest_k in the comments but it broke the Maven