# Error occurred during initialization of boot layer java.lang.module.FindException: Module SimpleJavaProgram not found

Tags: java, error-handling

I installed JDK version 15 to my computer. I am just starting to use Eclipse with Java and none of my programs work.
When I typed for exemple

```
public class RollingDice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Sara Jafari")
    }

}
```

and when I run it, it says:Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module SimpleJavaProgram not found

Please tell me what I should do to get my program working?
Thank you,

Sara

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a configuration problem. Did you check this discussion? [Eclipse - module not found when adding module-info.java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47511379/eclipse-module-not-found-when-adding-module-info-java)

Comment: I did not find the answer in this module.